# Can the Amazon Echo and Google Home interact and be used together?

Tags: amazon-echo, google-home

Can an Amazon Echo and Google Home coexist and interact?  We have an Amazon Echo which we use for simple on-off control at home.  We want to also get a Google Home for another room to test out.  Can they both be used to control the same devices or do they need a 1 to 1 correlation?

If they will not work together, would a smart hub help?

Comment: What sort of devices do you want to control ?

Comment: Obligatory video of the two systems coexisting and interacting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfCfTYZJWtI

Comment: @Helmar or [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5bYtcjWcPQ).

Comment: Either of those two qualify as an answer. If the OP wants them to interact in a specific way, the question does not indicate so. It just asks if they can interact, presumably meaning "interact at all, in any way".

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify your equipment, but I tell this:

I answered [this question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/what-is-the-nature-of-the-partnership-between-lightwaverf-and-google-home-amaz/1525) where the conclusion on that case was that the given equipment had support for several types of voice input devices.

Then I found [this comment](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/aw/review/B01M5C987C/R29P60PR2H54M2/ref=cm_cr_dp_aw_rw3/257-3165560-7861529) stating two other 3rd party services on (IFTTT and Alexa) **CAN** command the equipment ok. So the case with GoogleHome and Alexa would most probably be the same.

[Their site](https://www.lightwaverf.com/how-it-works/compatibility/) tells also the integration are made so that 3rd party device speaks their protocol and not other way around. That implies it is not taking too much effort from device to listen several inputs.

Generally the IoT equipment would need support for those multiple input protocols, or then the input devices should adopt to the protocol of the device. I have no experience on hubs, but have a gut feeling it would help in this case.